# background color and equal sized jradiobuttons

Tags: java, swing, background, layout-manager, jradiobutton

I have three radio buttons with background colors as shown below.
[image]

I need to stretch all of them to same size so that the background colors are uniform(with same width).Tried adding `setWidth(Dimension d)` but it's not working.

```
public class TrafficLights {
JFrame frame;
JRadioButton stop,go,wait;
JTextField signal;
ButtonGroup grp;
Dimension dim = new Dimension(200,30);
public TrafficLights(){
    frame = new JFrame("Traffic Lights");
    frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    stop = new JRadioButton("Red");
    stop.setBackground(Color.RED);
    stop.setSize(dim);      

    wait = new JRadioButton("Orange");
    wait.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    wait.setSize(dim);

    go = new JRadioButton("Green");
    go.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    go.setSize(dim);

    grp = new ButtonGroup();
    grp.add(stop);grp.add(wait);grp.add(go);
    frame.getContentPane().add(stop);
    frame.getContentPane().add(wait);
    frame.getContentPane().add(go);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300,200));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout`, then add the buttons to the panel and the the panel to the frame:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1) );
panel.add(button1);
...
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Comment: Yes I was able to do it with GridLayout and a JPanel.Thank you.
Is there any other shortcut?Because it's getting complicated as i keep adding components

Comment: @Pradeep, I find dividing the screeen into logicaly grouping of components is the easiest was to design the GUi. There are no shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `GridLayout(int rows, int cols)`:

```
    frame = new JFrame("Traffic Lights");
    frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(3, 1) );
    frame.add(panel);

    stop = new JRadioButton("Red");
    stop.setBackground(Color.RED);
    stop.setSize(dim);

    wait = new JRadioButton("Orange");
    wait.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    wait.setSize(dim);

    go = new JRadioButton("Green");
    go.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    go.setSize(dim);

    grp = new ButtonGroup();
    grp.add(stop);
    grp.add(wait);
    grp.add(go);
    panel.add(stop);
    panel.add(wait);
    panel.add(go);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

For more infos see: [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)